# Can i format output of matlab command such that i can use it to declare a new variable?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab

It's best explained with an easier example. Say some script in MATLAB gives me a cell array of strings:

```
temp = dir;
names = {temp.name}'

ans = 
'folder1'
'folder2'
'file1'
```

I would like to use this output in another script, in another matlab session. Ideally, in the second script i would write

```
names = {'folder1', 'folder2', 'file1'}
```

but this means copypasting the output right under "ans = " and then manually adding the commas and curly brackets. In my case the cell array is quite large so this is undesirable. Even more it feels clumsy and there could be an easier way. Is there any way to make matlab print the output in such a way that i do not have to do this?

Exactly the same thing would be nice to know for matrices instead of cell arrays!!

I am aware of saving the variable in a .mat file and loading it, but i was wondering if the above is also possible (it would be cleaner in my case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would advise the use of a cleaner way of handling this (such as mat files).
But then again sometimes the time spent setting these up is just not worth it for simple tasks which are unlikely to be repeated much...

For matrices there is a builtin function to do this, for cells however we would need produce a sting with the required format...

### Matrix

For 1d or 2d matrices `mat2str` provides this functionality

```
mat2str(eye(2))
ans =

[1 0;0 1]
```

---

### Cell

However to my knowledge there is no such builtin function for cells.
For a 1d cell array of strings the following will give the output in a copyable format:

```
['{',sprintf('''%s'' ',names{:}),'}']
ans =

{'folder1' 'folder2' 'file1' }
```

note: the stings in the cells cannot contain  the `'` character

Comment: You are not adressing this part "and then manually adding the commas and curly brackets."

Comment: Did you try running the code + copy pasting the output? The curly braces are added and spaces are used instead of commas (as Matlab will treat them as element separators like commas but with the advantage of not having to work around the trailing separator as Matlab will ignore the space)

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, you are getting the `names` output from one script and want to use it within another script. Since you then cannot pass it as function argument, you are currently copying it over. One could do that with eval and copy&paste around:

```
names = {'folder1'
'folder2'
'file1'};

% create the command
n = length(names);
cmd = sprintf(['names = {',repmat('''%s'', ', 1, n-1) ,'''%s''}'], names{:}); % '%s, %s, ...., %s' format
% cmd contains the string: names_new = {'folder1', 'folder2', 'file1'}

% eval the cmd in script 2
eval(cmd) % evals the command names = {'folder1', 'folder2', 'file1'}
```

But this is generally very bad practice as it gets insanely hard to debug if something goes wrong somewhere. Also it makes you copy and paste things around, which i feel is uncomfortable. How about storing them in a txt file and loading them in the second script? It gets things done autmatically.

```
names = {'folder1'
'folder2'
'file1'};

% write output to file
fid = fopen('mynames.txt', 'w'); % open file to write something
fprintf(fid, [repmat('%s, ',1, n-1), '%s'], names{:});
fclose(fid);

% here comes script 2
fid = fopen('mynames.txt', 'r'); % open file to read something
names_loaded = textscan(fid, '%s');
names_loaded = names_loaded{:};
fclose(fid)
```

Comment: Storing them as text files is a nice idea but in this case i was really looking for something like RTL posted. Thanks though!

Comment: @Joachim well the string stored in the variable ``cmd`` is exactly what you asked for. Either post this string in your script 2 or evaluate it with eval.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that you have a variable in 1 place, and want to use it in a different case.

In that situation you don't want to copy the output matlab generates, you just want to save the value itself.

After finding the result just do this:

```
save names
```

Later you can load this variable with

```
load names
```

Check `doc save` and `doc names` for more extensive examples. You may for example want to save all relevant variables in a file with a more generic name.

Comment: Note that if you actually use the functions 'together', you probably don't even need to use save, but can just use the variable as output of one function and input to another function.